# How to match string between two strings in a file and manipulate the matched string with sed?

Tags: bash

I am trying to manipulate a file using sed which contains text and the program should match the info between the two strings and add a new space before each line in the file between the matched strings .

part of file looks like this :

```
Change: ****
Client: ****
User:  manny

Status: pending

Description:
this is example text
this is example text
this is example text

Files:
//network paths
//network paths
```

i am trying to manipulate this file to match the text between Description and Files and introduce a white space before each line in matched text .

end result should look like this :

```
Change: ****
Client: ****
User:  manny

Status: pending

Description:
 this is example text
 this is example text
 this is example text

Files:
//network paths
//network paths
```

I have tried this command :

`sed -i -e 's/Description:(^.*)Files:/ / ' filename.txt`

its not working as i expected to . now when i tried just to add white space before each line with 
`sed -i -e 's/^/ /' filename.txt`

this works fine while introducing whitespace before each line in the file .

Someone suggest point me out where i am going wrong and maybe how to achieve the expected solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Between two patterns add a space at the beginning of each line, exclusively.

```
sed '/^Description:/,/^$/{//!s/^/ /}' file
```

Concerning `//`, it's described in [POSIX sed specification](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/sed.html#tag_20_116_13_02) as follows:

> If an RE is empty (that is, no pattern is specified) sed shall behave as if the last RE used in the last command applied (either as an address or as part of a substitute command) was specified.

Given your sample its output looks like:

```
Change: ****
Client: ****
User:  manny

Status: pending

Description:
 this is example text
 this is example text
 this is example text

Files:
//network paths
//network paths
```

---

In order to cover both cases that there may or may not be a blank line before `Files:`, this can be used:

```
sed '/^Description:/,/^Files:/{//!s/^./ &/}' file
```

Comment: Much shorter but perhaps more difficult to understand. +1

Comment: thank you for the reply , it worked . I have a small question , How does this regex match text only between Description: and Files: as i dont see any check for FIles: in the given regex ?

Comment: ^$ means blank line. There is a blank line before the word 'Files' and its the first blank line after 'Description:'

Answer (score 2):

Not very elegant, but it works.

```
sed '/^Description:/,/^$/{ /^Description\|^$/b; s/.*/ &/}' file
```

Output:

```
Change: ****
Client: ****
User:  manny

Status: pending

Description:
 this is example text
 this is example text
 this is example text

Files:
//network paths
//network paths
```

Answer (score 0):

When you are not sure that you can use a blank line as the last line, you can do

```
sed '/Description:/,/Files:/ s/^/ /; s/ \(Description\|Files\):/\1:/' file
```

or

```
d="Description"
f="Files"
sed "/$d:/,/$f:/ s/^/ /; s/ \($d\|$f\):/\1:/" file
```